# Has the number of answers that turns a question into CW changed?

Tags: support, community-wiki, rules

My question: [How can I explain why DRM cannot work?](https://superuser.com/questions/14224/how-to-explain-drm-cannot-work) just changed into a community wiki, and I cannot figure out why.

As far as I recall it needs to hit 30 answers before it automatically changes, but it has not hit that point yet... has this limit changed recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Started at 30. Then changed to 10. Right now answer count needs to hit 15 before it goes all wiki.

See the discussion on [Reducing the community wiki threshold on SuperUser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6814/reduce-community-wiki-force-threshold-to-15-answers-on-superuser).

Comment: Thanks... tried to find a post like that, but my search skill failed me. (plus there's a lot of posts discussing CW)

Comment: You don't use the search. You use divination to find things on SOFU.